# Variable marker sizes in Seaborn `pairplot` scatter diagrams

Tags: seaborn

I'd like to be able to assign the sizes of markers in Seaborn `pairplot` scatter diagrams. However, `pairplot` appears to *require* a long-form dataframe as input, and attempting to specify a scatterplot `size` thusly:

```
import seaborn as sns
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
spp = sns.pairplot(penguins)
spp.map_offdiag(sns.scatterplot(size='body_mass_g'))
```

… leads to the following error:

`ValueError: The following variable cannot be assigned with wide-form data: 'size'`

… which appears to indicate that the data which is passed to the `scatterplot` instances is in wide-form.

It would appear there's a mutual incompatibility here, but is there a way to do this?

Comment: A workaround seems to be `sns.pairplot(data=penguins, kind='scatter', plot_kws={'size': penguins['body_mass_g']})`.

Comment: Seems to work, thanks. You might want to transfer that comment into an answer, though…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have gradient colors and marker sizes for seaborn pairplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68908419/7758804)